# Why incorrect return type

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, flatmap

line .flatMap(WordsUtil::getWords) is error - Bad return type in method reference: `cannot convert java.util.List<java.lang.String> to java.util.Iterator<U>`

```
return lines.map(String::toLowerCase)
              .flatMap(WordsUtil::getWords)
              .mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<>(w, 1))
              .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b)
              .mapToPair(Tuple2::swap)
              .sortByKey(false).map(Tuple2::_2).take(topX);
```

Code method:

```
 public static List<String> getWords(String line) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    BreakIterator breakIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    breakIterator.setText(line);
    int lastIndex = breakIterator.first();
    while (BreakIterator.DONE != lastIndex) {
        int firstIndex = lastIndex;
        lastIndex = breakIterator.next();
        if (lastIndex != BreakIterator.DONE && Character.isLetterOrDigit(line.charAt(firstIndex))) {
            words.add(line.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex));
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

why i have this error?

Comment: Read the error message: `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.List<java.lang.String> to java.util.Iterator<U>`. So, what should the referenced method (WordsUtil::getWords) return? What does it return?

Comment: i see List<String>,ok but why this is correct? https://github.com/Jeka1978/spark-training-kiev-2016/blob/master/src/main/java/songs/TopWordsServiceImpl.java

Comment: Most probably because the code you linked to uses an old version of Spark, where the return type was Iterable (which List is), and not Iterator. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html

Comment: yes( in example using spark-core_2.10
         and i use 2.3.2 version(

Comment: @Alexandr the example that you point to is using Spark 1.6.1. See https://github.com/Jeka1978/spark-training-kiev-2016/blob/master/pom.xml#L13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flat map's function needs to return an Iterator:

```
.flatMap(w -> WordsUtil.getWords(w).iterator())
```

Comment: but why this is correct? https://github.com/Jeka1978/spark-training-kiev-2016/blob/master/src/main/java/songs/TopWordsServiceImpl.java